# How to populate statistics by Json data with dynamic keyword?

Tags: android, json, android-tablelayout, android-gridlayout

I have a json which I have parsed from a remote server. Here is the Json format.

```
{
  "Jan 01, 2020": [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "value": "25/25"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "value": "25/25"
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "value": "1/25"
    }
  ],
  "Jan 02, 2020": [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "value": "25/25"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "value": "4/25"
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "value": "1/25"
    }
  ],
  "Jan 03, 2020": [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "value": "2/25"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "value": "25/25"
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "value": "1/25"
    }
  ]
}
```

As the Json has dynamic keyword I have used `Map<String,Set<Statistic>>` to parse the data.But unable to populate the statistics as the picture given below.
`Statistic` class have two properties `name` and `value`.

[image: statistic table]

Comment: I have populated header separately by taking the keys of `Map`. But how will I print horizontal and vertical data which is also dynamic. I mean the rows and columns are not defined. They may increase or decrease based on the Json coming from the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private TableLayout mTableLayout;
  mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById( R.id.tableInvoices );
        mTableLayout.setStretchAllColumns( true );
public void loadData(){

        gross = sharedPreferences.getFloat( "Gross", 0 );
        float weight = sharedPreferences.getFloat( "weight", 0 );

        c = Calendar.getInstance();`enter code here`
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yy" );
        String strDate = sdf.format( c.getTime() );
        SimpleDateFormat sd1f = new SimpleDateFormat( "hh:mm" );
        String strtime = sd1f.format( c.getTime() );
        info = new Model_Info( weight, strDate, strtime );
        detail.add( 0,info );       
int rows = detail.size();
        //Model_Info info = null;
        mTableLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i <rows; i++) {
            info = detail.get( i );
            if (info.weight == 0.000){
                Toast.makeText( context, "Invalid weight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            } else {

                // data columns
                tv = new TextView( this );
                tv.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );

                tv.setGravity( Gravity.LEFT );

                tv.setPadding( 5, 0, 0, 0 );
                tv.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.table_border );
                tv.setText( String.valueOf( i+1 ) );
               tv.setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,textSize );
                tv.setTextColor( Color.parseColor( "#000000" ) );
                tv2 = new TextView( this );
                tv2.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );
                tv2.setGravity( Gravity.LEFT );

                tv2.setPadding( 5, 0, 0, 0 );

                tv2.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.table_border );
                tv2.setTextColor( Color.parseColor( "#000000" ) );
                tv2.setText( df.format( info.weight ) );
                 tv2.setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize );


                tv3 = new TextView( this );
                tv3.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );

                tv3.setGravity( Gravity.LEFT );
                tv3.setPadding( 5, 0, 0, 0 );

                tv3.setBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( "#ffffff" ) );
                tv3.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.table_border );
                tv3.setTextColor( Color.parseColor( "#000000" ) );
                tv3.setText( info.date + " " + info.time );
                tr_total.setText( String.valueOf( df.format( Total_Weight() ) ) );
             tv3.setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize );


                // add table row
                final TableRow tr = new TableRow( this );
                tr.setId( rows + 1 );
                TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams( TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
                trParams.setMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
                tr.setPadding( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
                tr.setLayoutParams( trParams );
                tr.addView( tv );
                tr.addView( tv2 );
                tr.addView( tv3 );
                final View vline = new View( this );
                vline.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0 ) );
                mTableLayout.addView( vline );
                mTableLayout.addView( tr, trParams ); } }}
```

Use this format for insert the data from json to tablelayout.And your table will look like the image i have attached..[image]